# Crashlytics plugin destroys my project

Tags: android-studio, crashlytics

I am trying to integrate Crashlytics into my app using their supplied plugin in Android Studio.
When I get to apply changes step I click next and then it says I should build the project. When I try to build I start getting

No resource found errors

And get

Error:(2) Error parsing XML: prefix must not be bound to one of the reserved namespace names

The xml that the error is listed in is inside build folder of one of my library projects, it's name is values.xml and it worked without a problem before I ran the Crashlytics plugin.
Also after running the plugin I cannot build the project from IDE or using gradle from console anymore even after running gradle clean I also can not do git revert because it says none of the files were changed. Only way to restore my project to previous state is to delete the folder and clone it again from remote.

Does anyone know what is going on? 
What does this plugin do to my build folder?

Additional info:
I am using the latest version of Android studio from Beta channel.
I downloaded latest Crashlytics plugin today.
And these the are versions of sdk and build tools set in my gradle build
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 19
        compileSdkVersion 21
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

Comment: Running into the EXACT same issue. Will answer back if I find a valid solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my problem thanks to some git pointers from a colleague. 
Actually I newer managed to make the plugin work but implemented crashlytics manually by following the docs.

Here is the solution to avoid cloning the project again.

The problem is created by resource merging of file com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
with the rest of resource xmls.
When you run the plugin even before pressing the next step to apply changes to files plugin will create this xml inside 
src\main\res\values\

Do note that in my case these values were created inside a library project because that was the only project that had default project structure. All the rest of the projects including the application have custom structure and apparently crashlytics plugin doesn't respect these customizations.
My problem with git was that Android studio doesn't see this file because it was added by other tool and to git working directory is clean since Android studio didn't correctly call git add on this file.

Also note that when running the plugin another file is created inside assets folder called crashlytics-build.properties. This file doesn't break the build but might have some unwanted effects. This file is apparently used to "identify individual builds of your Android application". Why do they use this data instead of data provided in manifest (in my case populated correctly by our build script) is still a puzzle to me and I suspect there are probably many bug reports open asking why their version names differ...

Here is a documentation link to add crashlytics manually https://dev.twitter.com/fabric/android/integrating

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how to solve this problem based on your post..I had to manually delete the com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml files in some of my lib projects..so annoying.

Comment: Actually yes, that was how I solved it too. After that I stopped using the plugin and just manually added required changes to the project. Just follow these steps https://dev.twitter.com/fabric/android/integrating

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. If I remember correctly, here's what I tried:

- `ionic build android` (failure)
- `ionic platform remove android`
- `cordova platform remove android`
- `cordova plugin remove cordova-crashlytics-plugin`
- `./platforms/android/cordova/clean`
- `cordova platform add android`
- `ionic build android` (success)
- `cordova plugin add https://github.com/4sh-projects/cordova-crashlytics-plugin`
- `ionic build android` (success)

If that doesn't work for you let me know and I'll have to look over this again. I did some extra steps trying to figure this all out so ya.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I don't really get all the steps you listed here but that is probably because you are using ionic and cordova and  my app is written in Java. Generally I think you too managed to solve your problem by removing some artifacts from values files that plugin adds. Please see my answer for more detail what exactly I dd.